# SQL delete objects having and id range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to create a function in sql server that take as input an id range and delete all the object in that range (included the start and the end).

Let's have for example:

```
delete_objects_with_id(id_start,id_end)
```

It will delete all the objects with the id in the range id_start and id_end.

The problem is that the id are of this form: `id_start=2017-0001` `id_end=2017-0050` is there a sql server function that iterate on a list given a range?

```
first_issue content id
2011-01-01  test    2011-0001
2012-10-01  test    2012-0001
2012-11-01  test    2012-0002
2012-11-01  test    2012-0003
```

Comment: Sample data in a tabular format would really help convey what your data looks like.

Comment: Is that varchar?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes it's a varchar.

Comment: @GordonLinoff question changed with example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no builtin SQL Server function that will iterate on a list given a range.

If the `id` values are always nine characters, in the format four numeric digits, a dash and four more digits, then a comparison to character strings would get you the id values.

That is, you could write a query (SQL SELECT statement) to return the id values in that range,

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM myobjects t
 WHERE t.id >= '2017-0001'
   AND t.id <= '2017-0050'
 ORDER BY t.id
```

and with that query, you could define a cursor loop, and loop through (iterate) through those id values returned.

If the `id` values aren't in a canonical format, then the range operation isn't necessarily going to work.  You'd need a mechanism to convert the `id` values into values that are canonical, so you can do a range.

But I'm not getting why you would need (or want) to iterate, if by "objects" you are referring to "rows" in a table. If you can write a SELECT statement that returns those rows, you could write a DELETE statement using the same predicates, and delete the rows in one fell swoop.

```
DELETE
  FROM myobjects
 WHERE id >= '2017-0001'
   AND id <= '2017-0050'
```

It's not at all clear what you are attempting to achieve, why you would need to "iterate". But a cursor loop is one way to do that.

---

Again, to answer the question you asked: No. There is no "sql server function that iterate on a list given a range"

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple workaround, Just remove `-` character and cast id as `BIGINT`
*(This will work assuming that the first part of the id is `year` value and the second part is an `id` for each year)*

```
   DELETE FROM TABLE_1
   WHERE CAST(REPLACE(id,'-','')  as BIGINT) >= CAST(REPLACE(id_start,'-','')  as BIGINT)
   AND CAST(REPLACE(id,'-','')  as BIGINT) <= CAST(REPLACE(id_end,'-','')  as BIGINT)
```

Or use `BETWEEN`

```
   DELETE FROM TABLE_1
   WHERE CAST(REPLACE(id,'-','')  as BIGINT) BETWEEN CAST(REPLACE(id_start,'-','')  as BIGINT)
   AND CAST(REPLACE(id_end,'-','')  as BIGINT)
```